# Geometric interpretation of a matrix

Tags: matrices, geometry

I'm supposed to be able to determine ***without calculations*** the determinant, inverse matrix, and n-th power matrix of the rotation matrix :

$\begin{pmatrix} 
cos\theta & sin\theta  \\ 
-sin\theta & cos\theta 
\end{pmatrix} $

Can someone explain to me how I can do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINTS**

The determinant tells you by how much a linear transformation transforms areas (for $2\times 2$)/ volumes (for $3\times 3$)/ etc.  So by what factor does this transformation change the area of say a square in the plane?  That'll be your determinant.

The inverse matrix is the matrix which does the inverse transformation.  What exactly does this matrix do?  How could that action be *undone*?

If you applied this matrix to a vector more than once, what should happen?

Comment: Ok if I understood correctly, the rotation doesn't change the area of a geometric figure so the determinant must be 1 and the inverse transformation is a rotation of angle $-\theta$

Comment: Yep.  That's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The matrices you wrote is a rotation in the plane by an angle of $\theta$. Therefore its inverse can be obtained by replacing $\theta$ by $-\theta$ as a rotation can be undone by a rotation with the opposite angle. Similarly its $n$th power will be a rotation by the angle $n\theta$. Finally as the determinant measures volumes and a rotation is an isometry (more precisely if two vectors $u$, $v$ determine a parallelepiped of volume $V$, and $T$ is a linear transformation, then the volume of the parallelepiped generated by $Tu$, $Tv$ is $det(T)\cdot V$) the determinant is one.

Comment: I don't see any value in immediately telling OP the answers when (s)he hasn't even given us any of his/her own thoughts.

Comment: @Bye_World I see your point, and I often give hints rather than full answers. In this case the OP asked for an explanation rather than a hint, and the problem looked to me of the kind which you either get immediately or you have a lot of trouble figuring out, so I gave a full answer, maybe I was wrong.